# Regex for value="..."

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am trying to do the following with regex...

```
value="7EB90267B9C141DB" />
```

Tried:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9]+"

(\w*)

"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"

"/^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$/"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: missing anchors `^` and `$`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You say "the following", but only a sample value and some regular expressions (which you say are incorrect) follow. What is the result of your current regular expressions match/replace/find, and how is it incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the following, any should work

- `value="(\w+)"`
- `value="(.+?)"`

Also make sure you set `$1$` as template.

You can test Regular Expressions using RegExp Tester mode of the View Results Tree listener:

[image: View Results Tree RegExp Tester]

See:

- [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](http://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Please see below the configuration which successfully fetches the data-

[image: Regular Expression Config]

[image: Result]

Remember to select the correct "field to check" in the Regular expression field .

Answer (score -1):

You have a white space after the plus, before the bracket. Remove it!

It should be:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\W*)
```